# Accessing java Maps & Lists as JavaScript Objects in Rhino

Tags: java, json, rhino

Is there a way to access Java Maps and Lists as JavaScript Objects in Rhino?

I have a Map which contains only other maps and lists of primitives and Strings, I'd like to pass this to a Rhino script and do stuff to it, and return the modified object back out to Java - but since they are java.util.Map and java.util.List Objects, I can't use standard JavaScript associative array syntax.
ie: `fooMap.get("keyName")` will work, but `fooMap.keyName` and `fooMap["keyName"]` will not.

I don't know if there is a Rhino-specific way to do this, or if there is some conversion/cast utility that will help.
Commons BeanUtils is not sufficient, because to convert a Map to a bean (which can be accessed via associative array syntax), you must first create a class which has all of the named mutators/accessors.  I won't know the structure of the object at runtime.

Comment: For that matter, I would like to be able to use `for (var in list) {...}` syntax rather than having to use an explicit iterator.

Comment: FYI, similar issue regarding [instantiating native objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8558405/instantiating-rhinoscript-native-objects-from-java-scala).

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at RingoJS. It has convenient wrappers for list and map for Rhino such as [this one](https://github.com/ringo/ringojs/blob/master/src/org/ringojs/wrappers/ScriptableMap.java)

Answer (score 2):

iterators seem to be the key!

if you want to iterate over all entries of a map, you could do the following

JAVA

```
//pass  the map and map.keySet().iterator() to the javascript
Object wrappedParameterMap = Context.javaToJS(parameterMap, scope);
ScriptableObject.putProperty(scope, "parameterMap", wrappedParameterMap);
Object wrappedParameterNames = Context.javaToJS(parameterMap.keySet().iterator(), scope);
ScriptableObject.putProperty(scope, "parameterNames", wrappedParameterNames);
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
while(parameterNames.hasNext()) {
  key = parameterNames.next();
  value = parameterMap.get(key);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/New_in_Rhino_1.7R3#JS.c2.a0Objects_implement_Java_collections claims that JS objects resp. arrays can now be cast to `Map` resp. `List`, but this does not seem like it would work for your use case.

Answer (score 0):

I had a [similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8598668/358006) that may be useful.  I tried created native rhino objects and copied data into them.

Answer (score 0):

Since Rhino 1.7.12 you can create ES6 lambdas and therefore create your own utility function like this:

```
function iterateMap(map, callback) {
    var iter = map.keySet().iterator();
    while(iter.hasNext()) {
        var key = iter.next();
        var value = map.get(key);
        callback(key, value);
    }
}
```

And then iterate like this

```
iterateMap(map, (key, value)=>{
    //...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The way to achieve this since Rhino 1.7.14 is to enable `Context.FEATURE_ENABLE_JAVA_MAP_ACCESS`.

This requires implementing a custom `ContextFactory`:

```java
public class MyContextFactory extends ContextFactory {
    @Override
    protected boolean hasFeature(Context cx, int featureIndex) {
        switch (featureIndex) {
            case Context.FEATURE_ENABLE_JAVA_MAP_ACCESS:
                return true;
        }
        return super.hasFeature(cx, featureIndex);
    }
}
```

Then, this factory can be used to instantiate contexts that has this feature enabled:

```java
Map<String, String> myMap = Map.of("message", "Hello from JavaScript");

ContextFactory ctxFactory = new MyContextFactory();
try (Context ctx = ctxFactory.enterContext()) {
    Scriptable scope = ctx.initSafeStandardObjects();
    ScriptableObject.putProperty(scope, "myMap", Context.javaToJS(myMap, scope));
    
    // Now map properties are accessible via `[key]` or `.key`:
    Object result = ctx.evaluateString(scope, "myMap.message", "<sample>", 1, null);
    String message = Context.jsToJava(result, String.class);
    System.out.println(message); // prints "Hello from JavaScript"
}
```